# How is $\text{Hom_R}(M,M)$ an $R$-algebra when $R$ is commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

My question/confusion comes from Proposition 2 of Section 10.2 in Dummit and Foote.  According to $(4)$, when $R$ is a commutative ring the set $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ is an $R$-algebra.  For the proof of this claim, the text states that defining $\varphi r = r \varphi$ for all $\varphi \in \text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ and $r \in R$ makes $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ into an $R$-algebra.

According to the definition of an $R$-algebra, we need there to be a ring (in this case, $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$) equipped with a ring homomorphism $f: R \rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ mapping $1_R$ to the multiplicative identity in $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ such that the subring $f(R)$ is contained in the center of $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$.

I don't understand how the condition "$\varphi r = r \varphi$ for all $\varphi \in \text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ and $r \in R$ establishes $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ as an $R$-algebra.  If I take an arbitrary $r \in R$ and map it to $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ under $f$, what is $f(r)$?  Is $f(r) = r\varphi$, where then $r\varphi$ is the map $(r\varphi)(m) = r(\varphi(m))$?  And if this is the case, does that means there exists different $R$-algebras for $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$, one for each of the maps $\varphi$?

Comment: It's probably easier to use the alternative description of $R$-algebra. See the paragraph under the definition on page 342 or whatever page $R$-algebra is defined on in section 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to be an $R$-algebra you have to know how to multiply things by each other, add them to each other, and multiply them by scalars from $R$. "Multiplication" will be composition, and addition will be pointwise; check that this distrbutes. Now the claim is that we can define
$$
r \cdot \phi(m)
$$
to be $r\phi(m)$. Sure, why not? You have to check that it distributes over addition, it does tho.

Comment: Does this mean that we get as many $R$-algebra structures as there are elements in $\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$?  One for each map $\varphi$?

Comment: Nope, if you want to know what $f$ is doing here, we have $f(r)=r\cdot\text{Id}$ where $\text{Id}$ is the identity map on $M$. In general, given an $R$-algebra $S$ with multiplication denoted $r\cdot s$ for $r\in R$ and $s\in S$, you get the corresponding structure map by taking $f(r)=r\cdot1$. Conversely, if you have such an $f$, you get the multiplication by defining $r\cdot s:=f(r)s$.